# Limit what do i "pull" in front of the brackets first

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am in a doubt with this simple problem. 
What is the correct answer to this problem:
$\lim_{x\to-∞}{\frac{x+3^x}{3x-3}}$

$(1)$  $\lim_{x\to-∞}{\frac{3^x{(\frac{x}{3^x}+1})}{3^x({\frac{3x}{3^x}-\frac{3}{3^x})}}}$

$(2)$  $\lim_{x\to-∞}{\frac{x{(1+\frac{3^x}{x}})}{x({\frac{3x}{x}-\frac{3}{x})}}}$

I know that $3^x$ "grows" faster so I think $(1)$ would be correct?

Comment: $3^{x}$ grows faster as $x \to \infty$, but decays rather than growing as $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y:=-x.$

Then consider :

$\lim_{y  \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{-y+3^{-y}}{-3y-3}.$

$\dfrac{-y+3^{-y}}{-3y-3} =(1/3)\dfrac{y-3^{-y}}{y+1}=$

$(1/3)\dfrac{1-3^{-y}/y}{1+1/y} .$

The limit $y \rightarrow \infty$ is?

Note: Your expression 2: You need to consider $3^x$ and $x \rightarrow - \infty$.

The above is similar to your version 2) ,  find it easier to deal with $y \rightarrow + \infty.$

Comment: Nice way Peter!

Comment: Thanks, Gimusi.

Answer (score 0):

$3^x$ doesn't grow as $x \to -\infty$; instead, it converges (*very* quickly) to zero.

If you try computing the limit via formula 1, after cancelling its of the form $((-\infty) + 1)/((-\infty) - \infty)$; not a form suitable for directly computing the limit, and with no obvious leads for further manipulation (other than undoing the previous step).

The only significant terms are the $x$ in the numerator and the $3x$ in the denominator; your formula 2 is a an effective way to isolate the significant part so that it can be cancelled out.

Answer (score 0):

No  $(2)$ is correct;  because $3^x\to 0$ as $x\to -\infty$.

However, it's so simpler with *equivalents*:

We have  $x+3^x\sim_{-\infty} x$ so
$$\frac{x+3^x}{3x-3}\sim_{-\infty}\frac{x}{3x}=\frac13.$$

Answer (score 0):

Simply note that for $x\to-\infty$ we have $3^x\to0$ thus the leading terms are $x$ and $3x$.